# Using independent column alignments in two rows of a tikz-cd environment?

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I have a sequence (of inclusions) that is too long for a single row, so I am forced to split it into two rows. The upper row contains 4 smaller objects (and 1 big one), while the lower row contains 3 much bigger objects. So, if both rows share the column alignment, the upper row gets stretched unnecessarily, even outside the page. This is what I have at the moment:

[image]

Notice that at the moment the last object in the upper row is the same as the first object in the lower row, but this is only temporary as I intend to connect both rows with a snake-like arrow.

> My problem is that if I put both rows in the same `tikzcd` environment, the upper row gets stretched to accomodate for the alignment of the lower row. Theoretically, I could split the sequence further, but it seems like a waste of space. Is there a way to connect both rows while each keeps its own column alignment?

Here is the latex code:

```
    $$
    \begin{tikzcd}
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook,"(VIII)"]{r} & 
    \hat{B}_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook,"(IX)"]{r} & 
    \tilde{B}_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook,"(X)"]{r} &
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}} bigg(\Big( \prod\limits_{k=1}^N 
    \tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k(U)^c \times \mathfrak{m}_k\Big)^c,\mathbb{Z}\bigg)
    \arrow[hook,"(XI)"]{r} & 
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}} (\tilde{U},\mathbb{Z})
    \end{tikzcd}
    $$
    $$
    \begin{tikzcd}
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(\tilde{U},\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[equal,"(XII)"]{r} & 
    \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^N ( \mathrm{pr}_k)^{-1}_\# 
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}}
    (\tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k(U)\times \mathfrak{m}_k,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[equal,"(XIII)"]{r} &
    \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^N ( \tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k)^{-1}_\# 
    B_1(\tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k(U),\mathbb{Z}) & 
    B_1(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook',"(XIV)",swap]{l}
    \end{tikzcd}
    $$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go is to remember the separate `tikzcd`s and to connect them via `overlay`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}
\[
   \begin{tikzcd}
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook,"(VIII)"]{r} & 
    \hat{B}_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook,"(IX)"]{r} & 
    \tilde{B}_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook,"(X)"]{r} &
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}} bigg(\Big( \prod\limits_{k=1}^N 
    \tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k(U)^c \times \mathfrak{m}_k\Big)^c,\mathbb{Z}\bigg)
    \arrow[hook,"(XI)"]{r} & |[alias=tr]|
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}} (\tilde{U},\mathbb{Z})
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\[  
    \begin{tikzcd}
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(\tilde{U},\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[equal,"(XII)"]{r} & 
    \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^N ( \mathrm{pr}_k)^{-1}_\# 
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}}
    (\tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k(U)\times \mathfrak{m}_k,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[equal,"(XIII)"]{r} &
    \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^N ( \tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k)^{-1}_\# 
    B_1(\tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k(U),\mathbb{Z}) & |[alias=br]|
    B_1(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook',"(XIV)",swap]{l}
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[-latex] (tr.east) to[out=0,in=0] (br.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Additional arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}
\[
   \begin{tikzcd}
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook,"(VIII)"]{r} & 
    \hat{B}_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook,"(IX)"]{r} & 
    \tilde{B}_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook,"(X)"]{r} &
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}} bigg(\Big( \prod\limits_{k=1}^N 
    \tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k(U)^c \times \mathfrak{m}_k\Big)^c,\mathbb{Z}\bigg)
    \arrow[hook,"(XI)"]{r} & |[alias=tr]|
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}} (\tilde{U},\mathbb{Z})
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\[  
    \begin{tikzcd} |[alias=bl]|
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}}(\tilde{U},\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[equal,"(XII)"]{r} & 
    \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^N ( \mathrm{pr}_k)^{-1}_\# 
    B_1^{\mathrm{ind}}
    (\tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k(U)\times \mathfrak{m}_k,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[equal,"(XIII)"]{r} &
    \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^N ( \tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k)^{-1}_\# 
    B_1(\tilde{\mathrm{pr}}_k(U),\mathbb{Z}) & |[alias=br]|
    B_1(U,\mathbb{Z}) 
    \arrow[hook',"(XIV)",swap]{l}
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[-latex] (tr.east) to[out=0,in=0] (br.east);
\draw[-latex] (tr.east) to[out=0,in=180,looseness=1.6] (bl.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks and sorry about forgetting to include the preamble (the geometry part, in particular). You are a real livesaver today :-) I would be interested in finding out also about the other ways to accomplish this (as I am researching now the code you posted) if you have further suggestions since you say this is one possible way to do it.

Comment: @M.G. Well, if you could point to something that you wish to have improved, I will be happy to look for a solution.

Comment: I am not really looking to improve anything, I am just trying to learn more about tikz, incl. obtaining the same result in different ways.

Comment: @M.G. To me this sounds a bit like solving the same cross word puzzle again. ;-) As long as you like the out put (of course with a backslash before `bigg` ;-) I think that is the most straightforward way to go.

Comment: I see, thanks for taking the time. I have a follow-up question: if I want to connect the last object of the upper row with the first object of the lower row via a snake-like arrow going between both rows, how should I draw the arrow? I have tried `\draw[-latex] (tr.south) to[out=-90,in=90] (br.north);`, but it produces a wobly line that intersects both rows (pictures).

Comment: @M.G. I added one more arrow. You need to name the node with `|[alias=...]|` in order to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am finally starting to navigate somewhat successfully in the pgfmanual and learning about all the options.